# ActiveMQ - worker threads and pool of tasks

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, worker

I have following scenario:

- some operation is invoked and as a result multiple tasks are created (thousands)
- they (their status and details) are stored in the database table
- i need to somehow execute these tasks on multiple nodes

So, the obvious way would be to send a JMS message for each created task (10000 tasks - 10000 messages) and a pool (per node) of consumers would perform them - but this looks like an overkill - a listener needs to fetch the task from DB anyway, it would be enough to notify it that it should work next task, as if - send one message ("work next task") and somehow set it to be delivered 10000 times.

How to approach this? is it really the best idea to send 10000 messages?

Also, ActiveMQ has this message scheduling thing [1] - maybe just set the period to 0 and repeat to 10000? Would that work correctly? Is there a better way other than those mentioned above?

[1] http://activemq.apache.org/delay-and-schedule-message-delivery.html

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can use Redis for storing ids of completed tasks(1..n). And use "set" data structure.

keys will be looks like tasklist:

each key will contains ids of completed tasks.

So when you started some job with 1000 async tasks. you generate some unique id for this job, and send with task ID, when task will be completed worker(who process this task) should add this id in DB(Redis). and when last worker save id in DB and size of set equal size of tasks (you should check it after each task) — all tasks completed so you can send another message or make anything else.

Redis provide very fast access and very fast few data structures.